# Open a class file from within the source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a hard time finding the right search term for this question. When I'm viewing source code in eclipse it would be nice if there was a way I could click on a referenced class and have it open that file in the editor. For example:

```
My_Object myObject = new MyObject();
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I could click on `My_Object` (which is a file in the project) and have it open it in the editor? Also it would be nice if there is a way to do the same thing with a method. I'm always opening files and scanning my code for a particular class or method. I assume this functionality exists but I can't figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With the Object hi-lighted, press 'F3' to open the deceleration. You can also hold control and left click, and you can also, with the object hi-lighted, right click and select open deceleration.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using Eclipse for years and can't believe I never thought to see if this feature existed...This is going to save me a TON of time.

Comment: Not a problem. Right clikcing any text will reveal a whole slue of available options that can be really helpful. If I helpeb, be sure to upvote and accept :)

Comment: "And the debugger will work within that source too! " 
Can you elaborate on this a bit more? 

Can't upvote as I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

left click on `My_Object` with **Ctrl** pressed